# How can i give json input in my web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, json, google-app-engine, web-applications

I am working with a web application which accepts json object, parses it and create a User object. I want to give this json input in gson.fromJson(jsonData, User.class);:

```
 {
   users:[{
   name: "Jack",
   email: "email1",
   friends:[{
       name: "name2",
       email: "email2",

    }]
 }]
}
```

what should i do to give this json object in place of jsonData. I am working with google app engine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Gson, please read doc [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html).
As `jsonData` you can pass string with your json or Reader which streams your json data.

UPD: In your case you need to deserialize array, so use it as

```
String jsonData = "{"
   "users:[{ " +
   "name: 'Jack', " +
   "email: 'email1', " +
   "friends:[{ " +
   "    name: 'name2', " +
   "    email: 'email2', " +
   "  }] " +
   "}] " +
"}";
User[] users = gson.fromJson(jsonData, User[].class);
```

GSon uses reflections to set properties, so make sure you have setters for all properties in json, like `User.setName`, `User.setEmail`, `User.setFriends`, ..

Comment: I am sorry. i read that before but i couldn't understand. I simply want to give that json syntax as an input. I will be very thankful if you will write couple of lines of code to show how can i do that. Thanks

Comment: I updated answer with code sample. GSon uses reflections to set properties, so make sure you have setters for all properties in json, like `setName`, `setEmail`, `setFriends`, ..

Comment: string literal are not properly closed by ". this is the error

Comment: I have all setters and getters. can't make string because of this error: string literal are not properly closed by ". thats why i am asking about how to create a string and give it in place of jsonData

Comment: getting this error:   HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /showuser. Reason:

    com/google/gson/Gson
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson     any idea? i have import all gson libraries.

Comment: Did you put libraries to WEB-INF/lib? These problems are not related to initial question really

Comment: Thanks JustYo. Yeah you are right that problem was not related to initial question. Its very kind of you that you still replied. Thanks again